# missing region in disparity map

Tags: c++, opencv, disparity-mapping

i am currently working on stereo processing using opencv2.3 and a Pointgrey Bumblebee2 stereocamera as an input device. Acquiring images is done via the *libdc1394*.

My code for rectification and stereo processing is the following:

```cpp
void StereoProcessing::calculateDisparityMap(const Mat &left, const Mat &right, Mat &disparity_map)

  Mat map11, map12, map21, map22, left_rectified, right_rectified, disp16;

  // Computes the undistortion and rectification transformation maps
  initUndistortRectifyMap(this->camera_matrix1,
        this->distance_coefficients1,
        this->R1,
        this->P1,
        this->output_image_size,
        CV_16SC2,
        map11,
        map12);
  initUndistortRectifyMap(this->camera_matrix2,
        this->distance_coefficients2,
        this->R2,
        this->P2,
        this->output_image_size,
        CV_16SC2,
        map21,
        map22);

  // creates rectified images
  remap(left, left_rectified, map11, map12, INTER_LINEAR);
  remap(right, right_rectified, map21, map22, INTER_LINEAR);

  // calculates 16-bit disparitymap
  this->stereo_bm(left_temp, right_temp, disp16);

  disp16.convertTo(disparity_map, CV_8U, 255 / (this->stereo_bm.state->numberOfDisparities * 16.0));
}
```

This works fine except for a black left border in the disparity map, which is the following:

[image: Disparity map with black border on the left side]

The input images are these two - unrectified as you can see ;) :
[image: left unrectified image]
[image: right unrectified image]

So my question is now: 
Is this normal behaviour? Or do you see any mistake i have done so far?
As another information, the rectification works fine

Comment: You might access you access your pixel using a loop where you have inverted rows and cols ?

Comment: I do not access pixel except for the mentioned opencv-functions, and they fetch the image size out of the input images, so i guess no :(

Comment: what is this->output_image_size ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The width of the missing region is equivalent to the number of disparities used in stereo_bm. It is a normal by-product of `stereo_bm algorithm`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens because the algorithm computes the disparity by matching blocks around pixels from the left image to blocks around pixels in the same row in the right image (assuming images are rectified). Since there is a region where there is no overlap between the views from the left camera and the right camera, the algorithm can't find a match for the blocks around pixels within this region. The width of the "missing" region equals the parameter "number of disparities" because the algorithm gives up trying to match a given block after "number of disparities" attempts (in the same horizontal row as the pixel in the left image). I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough. If you wish to get more details about how it works, there is some code in http://siddhantahuja.wordpress.com/2010/04/11/correlation-based-similarity-measures-summary/.